# How to align operands in c++-mode?

Tags: c++, align

I'm trying to get Emacs to align operands vertically.

#### Current behaviour

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void main()
{
    std::cout << 1 + 2
        + 3;
    return 1 + 2
        + 3;
}
```

#### Wanted behaviour

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void main()
{
    std::cout << 1 + 2
                 + 3;
    return 1 + 2
           + 3;
}
```

My research so far suggests that I probably want to add something to `align-rules-list`, but I can't figure out what. `c-show-syntactic-information` on the continued line returns:

> Syntactic analysis: ((statement-cont 76))

#### Update

I've found out that I probably can solve my problem with `c-offsets-alist`. The following snippet lines up assignments, strings and cascaded calls correctly, but it doesn't work for streams and `return`.

```lisp
(setq c-offsets-alist '((statement-cont . (c-lineup-assignments
                                           c-lineup-math
                                           c-lineup-string-cont
                                           c-lineup-cascaded-calls
                                           +))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adapt the output of

```lisp
c-guess-view
```

It will give you something like:

```lisp
(c-add-style "STYLE NAME HERE"
         '("gnu"
           (c-basic-offset . 7) ; Guessed value
           (c-offsets-alist
            (defun-block-intro . 4) ; Guessed value
            (defun-close . 0)   ; Guessed value
            (defun-open . 0)    ; Guessed value
            (statement . 0)     ; Guessed value
            (statement-cont . +)    ; Guessed value
            (topmost-intro . 0) ; Guessed value
            (access-label . -)
            ......
```

Change the guessed value as you wish, and execute the function.

Comment: That works for `return` because `c-basic-offset` is set to 7. But that also changes the indentation of all other blocks and doesn't work for `cout`.